# sumatoria de valores en atributo de input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy estancado en lo siguiente: necesito hacer una sumatoria de los valores que tienen los inputs number, para con esto hacer una comparación con el atributo "surtido" que tengo declarado. A ver si me hago entender: al principio tengo el siguiente código:

```
<div class="SurtirPedido">  
 <div class="NEW8 allenar">
  <div class="row">
   ...
   <div class="col-3 full">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ProductoCantidad" name="ProductoCantidad" surtido="0" value="3" readonly>
   </div>
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

La clase "NEW8" se llena dinámicamente agregando un div con clase row por cada producto seleccionado y que coincida con la clase "NEW8", lo que hace que se tenga la siguiente estructura:

```
<div class="SurtirPedido">
 <div class="NEW8 allenar">
  <div class="row">...</div>
  <div class="row">
   ...
   <div class="col-3">
    <input type="number" id="agregarProsu" class="form-control agregarProsu" name="agregarProsu" min="1" step="1" value="1">
   </div>
   ...
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero es que se sume el valor del input number a lo que tenga el atributo surtido del inicio. E creado este [ejemplo](https://codepen.io/hugh_williams/pen/GRmqQZM?editors=1010) en codepen en el que en el pedido esta NEW8 con 3 piezas a surtir, y en la tabla justo existen las 3 piezas sumadas de dos lotes diferentes.

Intenté con el siguiente codigo:

```
$(".SurtirPedido").on("change", function(){
$(".allenar").find("input.agregarProsu").each(function(){
    var $total = $(this).closest('div.row').parent().children().children(".full").children();
    var subtotal = 0;
    if($(this).value !== ""){
        subtotal += parseFloat($(this).value);
    }
    $total.attr("surtido", subtotal);
  });
});
```

No me funciona, en el inspector de propiedades surtido="NaN". Ocupo que el atributo "surtido" sea igual al value en el mismo input "ProductoCantidad", Como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Creo que no logré entender muy claro lo que quieres con la explicación. Por lo que entiendo tienes que buscar en distintas partes del documento para extraer valores de inputs que son de "solo lectura" y eso parece muy complicado. En mi experiencia con JQuery, es más fácil asignar variables globales con los valores que quieres leer/escribir y luego, mediante eventos, cambias las variables globales y los valores de los inputs relacionados.

Comment: Yo le agregaria el attributo name con un valor igual a cada input que quieras sumar, y luego haces un selector que tome todos esos inputs en un array, pase los valores y le haces un reduce(), ejemplo $('input[name="sumarInputs"]').each(input => results.push(input.value))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando el name="agregarProsu" de tu input, y luego haciendo el selector para ese name.
Luego podes ir sumando a la variable, o hacer un reduce, o algo.

```js
var total = 0
$("#calcular").click(() => {

  $("input[name='agregarProsu']").each((index, inp) => total += parseInt(inp.value))
  
  console.log(total)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="agregarProsu" ></input>

<input name="agregarProsu" ></input>

<button id="calcular">calcular</button>
```